# Ajax/javascript problem, innerhtml not changing

Tags: javascript, ajax

index.php

```
<?php
    //grab product id's who need to be showed
    $pids = '1,2,3';
?>

<html>

<head>
    <?php include 'lol.js.php'; ?>
</head>


<body onload="update_timers();">


    <div id="timer_3183" class="timer countdown clearfix" title="1301994024"></div>
```

lol.js.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function update_timers()
{
    check_detail('<?=$pids?>', 'ajax.php');
}




function updatepage(str, pids)
{
      //loop through all the products, change time
      document.getElementById("timer_3183").innerHTML = document.frm.hide.value;
}

function check_detail(pids, strURL) 
{
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    var self = this;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', strURL, true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4)
            updatepage(self.xmlHttpReq.responseText, pids);
            //document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = self.xmlHttpReq.responseText;
    }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send("pids=" + pids); //this goes to PHP script via POST
}


</script>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php

    echo '
<form name="frm">
    <input type="hidden" name="hide" value="Some random text">
</form>';
?>
```

I'm trying to get the div in index page set to the value in ajax.php.

The line that's not working is:
document.getElementById("timer_3183").innerHTML = document.frm.hide.value;

If i replace it with a literal string, it works:
document.getElementById("timer_3183").innerHTML = "rand text";

But when i want to set it to "document.frm.hide.value;" expression, the value doesn't change when the page loads.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: But ... that form *is not part of the document yet* when you're trying to add it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know what that "loop through ..." comment means, but:

```
  document.getElementById("timer_3183").innerHTML = str;
```

seems like it'd do something more interesting. The form you want to add is in the XMLHttpRequest response text, right?  That's what your "ajax.php" file **returns** to the browser. At the point that the request succeeds, it's still just plain un-parsed text.  By stuffing that text into the "innerHTML" property of the target "drop zone" `<div>`, you give it to the browser for parsing.  When that's done, the form will be there inside that `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getElementById` again? I.e. assign some id, say `hide` to input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hide" value="Some random text" id="hide">
```

And write the JS code like this:

```
document.getElementById("timer_3183").innerHTML = document.getElementById('hide').value;
```